# Super slow deployments when using Solana CLI 16.x

Tags: anchor, solana-program, solana-cli, anchor-lang

My deployments are extremely slow since I have updated my Solana CLI to v16.8 but when I run:

```
anchor deploy
```

I get:

```
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
⠁   0.0% | Sending 263/517 transactions
```

Even when I am using a private paid RPC. Someone knows what is going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday was released the Solana CLI version `16.10`, it has fixed the deployment speed issues. Just update your Solana CLI by running:

```
solana-install update
```

Then this is what I did in my Anchor program to build the crates using latest Solana version:

- Update my crates: `cargo update`
- Clean my environment: `anchor clean`
- Rebuild my environment: `anchor build`

After this deploying your program should be fast again.